# Haskell, QuickCheck, falsify a (wrong) property:

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Is there a way to falsify this (wrong) property:

```
prop :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
prop xs = reverse xs == xs
```

When i Use QuickCheck and later VerboseCheck it gives 100 different forms of:

```
[(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),()]
```

Passed:
and the final result is:

```
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Answer (score 10):

It just so happens that

1. If you try to evaluate that in GHCi, it has to choose a particular instance type of `Eq a` to use, and with the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension normally enabled in GHCi, it chooses `()`.
2. For the type `()`, because it has only one (non-bottom) value, the proposition is actually *true*.

The simplest fix is to choose (almost) any other type by providing a type annotation:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> quickCheck (prop :: [Int] -> Bool)
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 4 tests and 3 shrinks): 
[0,1]
```